# Create a pull request in CodeCommit using a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, aws-codecommit

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for 2 separate environments: dev and prod. Upon the completion of the dev pipeline I have an EventBridge rule that is triggered which in turn will invoke a Lambda function. I would like the lambda function to create a pull request in CodeCommit to merge dev branch to main branch (where it should be manually approved). How can I got about implementing this Lambda function?

Comment: Lamda provides AWS SDKs support for your chosen runtime. You can create and use CodeCommit client to interact with the CodeCommit to commit, push and create PR.